Anyone knows the best way to create this segmented floor plane animation?
So what I would like to create is a segmented floor plane like the one shown in the images that I've attached. So the idea is that all the stroke segments have a smooth individual wave like flow that creates this sharp edged "waves" that with some offset staggering creates a very nice smooth flowing floor animation. If you would like to see the animation on playback, you can visit that instagram post here; https://www.instagram.com/reel/C_wXmkwMdJb/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link&igsh=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==
So if anyone has a way of creating this animation, let me know please :) Thnx!
Regard,
Lee




Have you tried Geometry Nodes? There are a lot of examples of proximity checks. The challenge is probably to keep these segments intact and separated.

Hi @Blunder, thnx for your suggestion. No I haven't looked into/tried Geo Nodes yet. I was hoping some one maybe knows how to do this effect with 'just' a mesh/planes/array/bend/wave kind of setup.
